# Changing class of div in aspx page using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a div in default.aspx which has a masterpage. Masterpage has a expand/collapse button. The the click of the button in masterpage I want to change the class of the div in default.aspx using javascript. The button in masterpage has other functionality. The javascript function is given bellow:

```
function toggleCollapseState(id,id1)
{
var obj = getObj(id);
var obj1 = getObj(id1);    
var objHomePageRightFixedWrapper = getObj('homePageRightFixedWrapper');
if(!obj)
    return false;

if(obj.className == 'tdSideMenuCollapse')
{
    var state = 1;
    obj.className='tdSideMenu';
    obj1.className='sidemenucollapsebutton';
    obj1.title = "Expanded";
    objHomePageRightFixedWrapper.className = "homePageRightFixedWrapper";
    //$(".homePageRightFixedWrapper").css("float", "right");
}
else
{
    var state = 0;
    obj.className='tdSideMenuCollapse';
    obj1.className='sidemenuexpandbutton';
    obj1.title = "Collapsed";
    objHomePageRightFixedWrapper.className = "homePageRightFixedFloatWrapper";
    //$(".homePageRightFixedWrapper").css("float", "left");
}

return true;
```

}

When debug through javascript function, its the div (homePageRightFixedWrapper) is showing className(homePageRightFixedWrapper/homePageRightFixedFloatWrapper), but same is now seen in the aspx page.

Thanks for all helps in prior.

Comment: So you are saying that the class name is set correctly, but the page doesn't look correct?   Can you post your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all ur help. I was missing the full id.

```
var objHomePageRightFixedWrapper = 
    getObj('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_homePageRightWrapper');
```

solved my issue.